# C coding and bug identification

Tags: c

I cant run the code below for some reason. tried a few compiler for debugging but no luck.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int mul5=0, mul3=0, final=0;
    int i=1;

    while (i<10){
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            mul3=mul3+i;
        else if (i%5==0)
            mul5=mul5+i;
        else
            i++;
    }

    final = mul3 + mul5;
    printf("%d\n", final);
}
```

Already tried `void` as the return type for `main` and an `int` return type with a return of 0.

Comment: You google the error message and find out what it means.

Comment: i dont get a message cause im using a plug for notepad++ and the compiler doesnt show the message error (another problem)

Comment: @djechlin: Should be obvious that there is no error message. The code will just run forever without ever printing anything.

Comment: sorry thought it was a compilation problem

Answer (score 4):

There are three cases: i % 3 = 0, i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 = 0, and the third case that neither i % 3 nor i % 5 are 0.

In which of these three cases is i increased by 1?

In which of these three cases do you want to increase i by 1?

PS. Your code is quite trivial, so it is easy to figure out what is wrong. However, you really really should tell *exactly* what is happening. Remember that we are far away from your computer and can't see what it's doing, and we can't read your mind either. Usually you just have to answer the following questions:

a. What are you doing. 
b. What do you expect to happen. 
c. What *does* happen.

Comment: after the three where checked. meaning in every loop of the while

Comment: That's the second question answered. Now answer the first question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is, you are not incrementing the value of `i` when the `if` and `else if` condition is true.
That's why the `while` loop is running infinite number of times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int mul5=0, mul3=0, final=0;
    int i=1;
    while (i<10)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0) //When this condition is true i should also be incremented
        {
            mul3=mul3+i;
            i++;
        }
        else if (i%5==0)//When this condition is true i should also be incremented
        {
            mul5=mul5+i;
            i++;
        }
        else
            i++; //Increment i when it is not increment in if and else if condition
    }
    final = mul3 + mul5;
    printf("%d\n", final);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop in your code.

What happens is that when the loop start executing is one of 3 conditions, i.e , 
1. Value of `mul3` will be increased
2. Value of `mul5` will be increased
3. `i` will be incremented

When the loop starts ,`i` is 1. Since `i%3==0` and `i%5==0` is false, `i` is incremented. The same happens when `i` is 2. But when `i` is 3, `i%3==0` is true. So `mul3` will be increased and thus the other two conditions are skipped. From then on, `i` will not change and thus it results in an infinite loop.

To make the `while` loop end, `i` has to be incremented after every loop. So all you have to do is remove the `else` that is before `i++;` and voilà ! Your bug is fixed!